# Creating a Code Challenge for Spotify API PKCE, Why Is It Not In Byte Form?

Tags: python, spotify

I am not sure if i can ask about the Spotify API but saw no other subreddit to put in.
I am trying to connect to Spotify API without the use of external packages (like Spotipy).

I am reading their documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce):

I decided to use the PKCE since I want to distribute a software and the user only needs to give their client_id (its open source)

In that case, I need to create a "code challenge", this is what I have:

```
SpotifyCodeChallenge = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(SpotifyCodeVerifier.encode()))
```

Yet this is the error I get:

[image: image here]

How would I fix this?

Comment: A hash is a string, try to convert an str object to a bytes object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SpotifyCodeChallenge = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(SpotifyCodeVerifier.encode('utf-8')).digest())
```

This will prob do it.